# Error message appearing twice when displayed

Tags: html, angular

I've constructed a modal which appears when there is an error. I'm displaying the message body based on an array which contains all my error message.

HTML:

```
<div class="popup_modal">
  <div class="content" style="width: 28em;">
    <div class="header" style="height: 5em;>
      <p >Error Details.</p>
      </div>
    <div id="msgBody" class="body" style="height: 40vh;>
      {{fetchMessage()}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS File:

```
fetchMessage()
{
var msg :string[] = [];
msg = this.getErrorMessage(this.messages); //this returns list of errors 
for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++)
{
  var element:any = document.createElement("p"); 
   element.innerHTML =  msg[i]+'\n';
  document.getElementById("msgBody").appendChild(element)

 }
 }
```

The problem is the error messages are repeated 4 times(even when the array returns only 1 item) and it multiplies every time I close and view the pop up modal. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Every time you call fetchMessage method it creates new elements (document.createElement("p");)

Comment: And I think this is not the best for show lists. I am not sure but maybe you are looking for ng-for directive.

Comment: It's because the fetchMessge method is called everytime change detection runs. You should avoid calling method from your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing code to :-

**1. If you really want to call method in template :-**

**TS :-**

```
fetchMessage()
{
var msg :string[] = [];
var msgBody = document.getElementById("msgBody");
msg = this.getErrorMessage(this.messages); //this returns list of errors 
msgBody.innerHTML="";
for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++)
{
  var element:any = document.createElement("p"); 
   element.innerHTML =  msg[i]+'\n';
   msgBody.appendChild(element)

 }
 }
```

**2. Better Way**

HTML :-

```
<div class="popup_modal">
  <div class="content" style="width: 28em;">
    <div class="header" style="height: 5em;>
      <p >Error Details.</p>
      </div>
    <div id="msgBody" class="body" style="height: 40vh;>
      <p *ngFor="let message of msg">{{message}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS :-

```
public msg: string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchMessage();
}
fetchMessage(){
  this.msg = this.getErrorMessage(this.messages); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is in the loop every time it iterates.....Best solution is to remove from the loop